# Edit Button - Swift - UIViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, edit

I'm new to the Swift language, as well as coding in general. I wrote an edit button in using the code:

```
{
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Update", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")
        success(true)


    })
    modifyAction.title = "Edit"
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
}
```

When pressed, I need the edit button to go to this UIViewController:

AddfreshreleaseViewController: UIViewController

How would I write that in?

**update**

I'm trying to link an edit button back to my UIViewController (AddfreshreleaseViewController). This code shows the edit button on the left when you swipe the cell towards the right, but when I added in the 'performSegue' to try and get back to the UIViewController the app crashes every time I swipe towards the edit button now. Any suggestions on how I can get this working?

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->            UISwipeActionsConfiguration?

{
let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Update", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
    print("Update action ...")
    success(true)

})
modifyAction.title = "Edit"
modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue

performSegue(withIdentifier: "addFreshRelease", sender: self)

return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])

}
```

Comment: Hey... did you try the solutions?

Comment: I did, your code is helpful! But I want this button to show up when I slide the cell towards the right. So, besides the code I already had to make the button show up, I'm not sure how to set that up in view.

Comment: The that should be asked as a different question.

Comment: Well, the code I provided makes it so when you swipe the cell to the right it reveals an edit button. I just can't figure out how to make that edit button take you back to the AddfreshreleaseViewController page.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand when pressing the button, you want to go to another window (UIViewController) so you have to create a `segue` and in your `UIButton` add:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: <YOUR_IDENTIFIER>, sender: self)
```

Comment: When I tried this I got the error: Cannot convert value of type 'AddfreshreleaseViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: Nevermind, I gave the UIViewController a title to fix that error. It now builds, but when I swipe that button the app crashes.